# Nethack Ubuntu - CTRL-P for message history not working?

Tags: technical-issues, nethack, linux, ubuntu

I installed nethack on ubuntu via the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install nethack-common nethack-console
```

For some reason I can't use <kbd>CTRL+P</kbd> to display message history. I've tried putting on and off caps lock, tried <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>, and even <kbd>CTRL+ALT+P</kbd> and nothing works. All it seems to detect is the <kbd>SHIFT-P</kbd> and asks me what I want to put on.

Comment: Why is this rated down? This seems like a perfectly valid question to ask and I have tried everything...

Comment: I'd presume either the key isn't set in nethack itself (check ~/.nethack.rc iirc) or something is grabbing the ctrl+p key combination such as the terminal and doing something with it.

Comment: @DouglasNewton I downvoted as it does not appear to be on-topic as gaming relate; at first glance it looked like it belongs on a different stackexhange site. I apologize if I was mistaken

Comment: @djsmiley2k I think you are right. BASH seems to use ctrl-p for command history. I tried running it in the xTerm but it won't work either (and looks terrible in comparison). My bad, I know BASH isn't a terminal but I switched terminals to try nonetheless (and since both run the same shell they would have the same issue).

Comment: @Wondercricket I understand - nethack sounds more like a network utility than a game, but it is definitely a game and one worth trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out <kbd>CTRL-P</kbd> was in fact working, but not in the way I expected.

<strike>The tty version of nethack displays a list of recent messages on the right side of the screen when using the command - so this is what I was expecting it to do. However, The offline version simply repeats the last message (or the ones prior to it) at the top of the screen.</strike>

Because I was trying different <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> combinations, I obviously used the put-on command ( <kbd>SHIFT-P</kbd>) at least once. Then when I tried  <kbd>CTRL-P</kbd>, the command was doing its job by displaying a recent message but it looked like it was merely interpreting it as another put-on command. Of course, I realised my mistake when I did other actions in the game which displayed different messages and tried  <kbd>CTRL-P</kbd> again.

EDIT: As hobbs pointed out, I hadn't set `msg_window` to <strike>`full`</strike> (alt.org uses`reversed`) and therefore wasn't getting the functionality I was used to when playing on the server.

I had to create a new configuration file, `~/.nethackrc` with `OPTIONS=msg_window:reversed` and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Setting the [msg_window](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options#msg_window) option in game or in `~/.nethackrc` to one of the other options besides `single`, probably `full`, will give you what you're used to. What you're playing *is* the tty version, just with different option defaults.

Comment: @hobbs Thank you so much, this is what I needed. I created a `~/.nethackrc` with `OPTIONS=msg_window:full`